# ¿Por qué la eñe se pronuncia como /ni/ en Buenos Aires?

Tags: pronunciación

Me he dado cuenta de que algunas personas de Buenos Aires pronuncian la eñe como /ni/ en vez de /ɲ/: *año* /'ani.o/.

Me parece particularmente interesante porque va en contra de la tendencia popular de los hispanohablantes de pronunciar la eñe hasta cuando se escribe -ni- (*niebla* suena como *ñebla*; el hipocorístico de *Antonio* es *Toño*).

Se suelen atribuir muchos rasgos del español argentino a la migración italiana, pero incluso el italiano cuenta con el fonema /ɲ/, escrito *-gn-* (no conozco otros idiomas itálicos allende el italiano estándar; igual y en ellos no figura).

Me pregunto si se sabe de dónde salió esta pronunciación, cómo se propagó, cuán esparcida está en el dialecto rioplatense, y si hay otros dialectos en los que esta pronunciación ocurra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay [un estudio muy reciente](https://rasal.sael.org.ar/index.php/rasal/article/view/7/5)¹ sobre la tendencia de los hablantes porteños a despalatalizar la *eñe* /ɲ/. El resultado es bastante claro: más de dos terceras partes de los hablantes estudiados despalatalizan la /ɲ/, generalmente desdoblándola en [nj] (/n/ + aproximante palatal), con diferentes frecuencias según el fonema que siga.

El estudio no buscó averiguar dónde se originó esta pronunciación ni cómo se propagó, pero halló que la despalatalización no se correlaciona con la edad del hablante, lo cual podría indicar que es un cambio fonético bastante antiguo. Esto tiene bastante sentido considerando la magnitud del fenómeno. Hay una leve tendencia a despalatalizar más en la población con menor nivel de instrucción.

En este estudio y en otros anteriores se menciona como hipótesis de origen de este cambio la pérdida del contraste entre un fonema alveolar y otro palatal que se dio al perderse /ʎ/ (la aproximante palatal lateral) a causa del yeísmo. Según esta hipótesis, al perderse la alternancia /l/–/ʎ/, la /ɲ/ queda aislada en el sistema fonológico. Otra posible causa planteada es que /ɲ/ tiene una carga funcional muy baja, es decir, hay muy pocas palabras donde se use, muy pocas donde contraste con /n/, etc. También es un fonema bastante restringido en su distribución.

La despalatalización de /ɲ/ ha sido registrada en varios dialectos tanto europeos como americanos, en cada caso con diferentes posibles causas. También existe en otras lenguas romances, incluyendo el francés y rumano. Algunos datos más, de la NGLE:

[image]

¹ Peña Arce, J. (2020). *Estudio sociolingüístico de la despalatalización de /ɲ/ en el español de la Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires.*